# Visual basic code in excel

Tags: vba, excel

This is my table:

[image]

I want to search data from raw table and then feed the data according to date and brand in selected m1,m2,m3,issue,wastage,extra,repack fields.
the problem here is that my table is not apdating as per my needs .
here my code is not updating data for brand 'b' of selected date.

This is my code:

```
Sub FindMatches()
    Dim oldrow As Integer
    Dim newrow As Integer
     For oldrow = 4 To 14
        For newrow = 3 To 20
            If Cells(oldrow, 12) = Cells(1, newrow) And Cells(oldrow, 13) = Cells(newrow, 1) Then  'date and brand
                    If Cells(1, 14) = Cells(newrow, 2) Then
                          Cells(newrow, 3).Value = Cells(oldrow, 14).Value ' m1
                    End If
                    If Cells(1, 15) = Cells(newrow + 1, 2) Then
                          Cells(newrow + 1, 3).Value = Cells(oldrow, 15).Value ' m2
                    End If
                    If Cells(1, 16) = Cells(newrow + 2, 2) Then
                                    Cells(newrow + 2, 3).Value = Cells(oldrow, 16).Value ' m3
                    End If
                    If Cells(1, 17) = Cells(newrow + 3, 2) Then
                                        Cells(newrow + 3, 3).Value = Cells(oldrow, 17).Value ' issue
                    End If
                    If Cells(1, 18) = Cells(newrow + 4, 2) Then
                                            Cells(newrow + 4, 3).Value = Cells(oldrow, 18).Value ' repack
                    End If
                    If Cells(1, 19) = Cells(newrow + 5, 2) Then
                                                Cells(newrow + 5, 3).Value = Cells(oldrow, 19).Value ' extra
                    End If
                    If Cells(1, 20) = Cells(newrow + 6, 2) Then
                    Cells(newrow + 6, 3).Value = Cells(oldrow, 20).Value ' wastage
                    End If
         End If

        Next newrow
        Next oldrow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with the following

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindMatches()

Dim rawRng As Range, newTableDateRng As Range, newTableBrandRng As Range, cell As Range, foundDate As Range, foundBrand As Range

Set rawRng = Worksheets("shet").Range("L3:T100")
Set newTableDateRng = Worksheets("shet").Range("C2:I2")
Set newTableBrandRng = Worksheets("shet").Range("A4:A100")

With rawRng    

    For Each cell In .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        Set foundDate = newTableDateRng.Find(What:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not foundDate Is Nothing Then
            Set foundBrand = FindValue(newTableBrandRng, cell.Offset(, 1))
            If Not foundBrand Is Nothing Then
                cell.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 7).Copy
                Intersect(foundDate.EntireColumn, foundBrand.EntireRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, , True
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

End With

End Sub


Function FindValue(rng As Range, value As String) As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set FindValue = rng.Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(value, rng, 0))
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

please note that all initial settings are specific to data "structure" as per your screenshot example. should you need to change it, you have to follow the same "pattern" (i.e. `rawRng` starts from the first "raw table" data row under the header, and so on). also note that the `7` number used in `cell.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 7).Copy` statement comes out from your posted data structure , where you need to copy values from "m1" to "wastage" fields included, and that you must then make sure that each "brand" rows group in "new table" must match this pattern (namely, have 7 rows)

Comment: If my answer fullfilled your question please accept it as the solution. Thanks

Comment: one more thing ...if these two tables are in two different worksheets then will this code work...

Comment: well, just try it.... hint: pay attention to those three `set ...` statements by the beginning of the macro

Comment: sir i want to include userform in the sheet name shet .
how would this be done with this code..

Comment: You must start a new question (perhaps "how to include a userform in a worksheet"). And I'd suggest you to be both as clear as possible as to your very needs

Comment: click Developer➜Controls➜Insert menu; select the most up-left item (the one with "Button Form Control" tooltip); drag the button shape onto the sheet with the wanted size and in the wanted place (but you can move/re-size it afterwards also); it automatically opens an "Assign Macro" form; select "FindMatches" in the listbox; click OK. and you're done!

Comment: THANKS ...
I WANT TO GO ON FURTHER AND DEVELOP IT TO FILL ONE MORE NEW SHEET OF PACKAGING MATERIAL (THAT WILL BE OF SAME FORMAT SHEET AS OF BRAND SHEET THE CODE U SHARE FOR)SIDE BY SIDE.
WHAT SHOULD I DO NOW?

Comment: IT WILL SAME MY A LOT OF TIME

Comment: you must start a new question, posting your actual code and giving details about the problems you encounter (what it does not that should do and/or what it does that shouldn't). the more you're specific with issues (limiting them by possibly one) and show your own efforts the more support you'll get. If I fulfilled your original question please mark the answer as accepted. If you find it useful also, you may want to up-vote it. thank you

Comment: i want to automatic update sheet 2 & sheet 3 from sheet 1 as per data.
it will be helpful if it gets resolved.
i am new to visual basic coding so unaware of its script but aware of c++.
what so ever the solution may be it will be helpful.
[the image is screen shot of the three sheets respectively as i was unable to upload three sheets]

[link]( http://i.stack.imgur.com/tskWA.png)

Comment: you must start a **_new question_**, like you did the 3rd of April!  Besides, I thought my answer both resolved your original question and proved _"very help full"_, but I must be mistaken...

Comment: i am not saying that your help was not helpful.

Comment: what i am trying to ask is using previous idea to update two sheets simultaneously.

Comment: for now we can say we are working on advancement of the last code.

Comment: SO rules are quite straightforward: 1) ask a question 2) if _that_ question gets an answer then mark this latter as accepted 3) if any answer is also useful then up-vote it 4) if the resolution of the original answer gives birth to a _new_ question than post it as such. The _original_ question and the _new_ one (and their corresponding answers, if any)  are completely disjointed